# How many people did the killer actually kill in the 1st season of True Detective

Tags: plot-explanation, true-detective

So I lost counting of how many people the killer in the first season of *True Detective* killed in the end.

- There was a murder at the start. The girl was found in the woods.
- Soon after we heard about a missing girl "Fontenot girl" presumably kidnapped by the same killer.
- Another girl was shown while investigating Rust.
- A boy was killed as we saw Rust and Marty took down the two killers/kidnappers in the first shootout. A girl was saved back then.
- After the final incident the police found bodies or evidence for at least 12 missing persons.

BUT Rust showed Marty a map where he pointed out many missing persons in the coastal area that he assumed to be killed by the same killer. But those bodies were not shown and not mentioned in the end. So how many people were killed in total by that killer? Are those all that I listed or there are others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came with the same question but a careful analysis tell us more than you think.

When Rust made the map, remember he did with all the victims and suspected crimes that appears to be from the case. Here's what it looks:

[image: Screen capture of the moment when he is showing the map]

He said after that that cases at the swamp was like a sort of match. Following the hypothesis that all the victims related at the swamp were taken by the killer, that give us a total of 28 victims.

And, as the question explained, a total of 12 missing bodies were found at the final crime scene. Assuming, in the map made by Rust there were included the first case at the episode 1 and also the Fontenot Girl, 12 victims confirmed at the final chapter of E1, 69 marks in the whole map discounting the swamp, 1 assassination during the scene where the kidnappers were killed without forget the swamps matches, this give us a total of **81 assassinations**.

***DISCLAIMER:*** The calculations were made by me, just watching the serie (again) and reviewing every step. This is not a total amount made by the production or anything related. If you have different numbers, I would like to see.

Comment: Okay so I think it's the closet we can get. I'm accepting it until someone claim something else later with proof. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is that final map actual people linked, or, since they had a dead perp and other bodies, a way for them to "solve" a whole bunch or crimes that would otherwise sit there and make them look bad? Not disagreeing, wondering what you think.